# Как работать с sepolicy в C++?

Tags: c++, документация, selinux

Не подскажете, где искать документацию по `libsepol` - библиотеке для работы с **sepolicy**? Вот только не надо говорить "загугли". Google тут вообще молчит. Официальный сайт *selinuxproject.org* об этой библиотеке лишь упоминается, Github Wiki у SELinux - тоже. Я искал что-то вроде:

```
Google > libsepol "doc"
// да, я умею пользоваться операторами поиска
```

И там только deb, rpm, apk пакеты libsepol! Скачал Alpine rootfs, там же libsepol-doc - и ничего толком не получил...

И да, меня интересует именно **libsepol**, не **libselinux**!

И ещё, не надо меня отсылать на Python или Ruby реализации libselinux и libsepol, мне строго C++ надо.

UPD: по python тоже инфы толком нету

Comment: Вот [исходники libsepol](https://salsa.debian.org/selinux-team/libsepol). Наверное, при желании можно разобраться чем она занимается

Comment: спасибо за наводку, посмотрю